# Iterate through multidimensional hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
  groceries=[{"bread"=>"2", "eggs"=>"3", "cheese"=>"1", "butter"=>"4"},
             {"juice"=>"3", "milk"=>"1", "tea"=>"1", "sugar"=>"1"}]
```

How do I iterate each hash and push into a separate array?
 I want to have something that looks like this:

```
 items = [["bread","eggs","cheese","butter"],["juice","milk","tea","sugar"]]
```

Comment: What if I wanted to keep the format but only return elements that have a length greater than five?

Comment: You mean, keep the keys with more than 5 characters?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
groceries.map(&:keys)
 => [["bread", "eggs", "cheese", "butter"], ["juice", "milk", "tea", "sugar"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the keys that have 5 or more characters :

```
p groceries.map{ |hash| hash.keys.select{ |key| key.length >= 5 } }
#=> [["bread", "cheese", "butter"], ["juice", "sugar"]]
```

If you only want at most 2 keys that have 5 or more characters :

```
p groceries.map{ |hash| hash.keys.select{ |key| key.length >= 5 }.first(2) }
#=> [["bread", "cheese"], ["juice", "sugar"]]
```

Comment: What if I only want to select the first two from each hash that have five or more characters? [["bread","cheese"],["juice","milk"]]

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.

Comment: @akuhn that confuses me greatly!